# What is causing the white block at the bottom of this page?

Tags: css

On [this page](http://www.thesmallbusinesslounge.com.au/our-team/) when you scroll down to the bottom a big block of white appears at the end of the page.

I've used the Chrome code inspector to set

```
html {height: 100%;}
```

and that resolved the problem immediately, but if I need to make a permanent solution, adding the same rule, or even

```
html {height: 100% !important;}
```

to the style sheet does not resolve the problem.

How do I remove the large block of white at the bottom of this page?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Your website has a script that overrides scrolling behaviour. Please don't do this as it messes-up user expectations, as well as consuming excessive battery life on laptops (Chrome reports you have handlers for mouse movement and scrolling that are fired on every frame).

Comment: I see. The website uses a template. Can you tell me which script is doing that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem div which is `<div id="top-panel-inner" class="dfd-header-responsive-hide">`

In app.css line 21362

// this line number may not meaningful, I got it from chrome inspect.

// just try to remind you, where you add these css.

There should a script that controlling this div, every 5s (roughly) the script runs.

```
#top-panel-inner {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden; // Add this will solve your problem immediately 
}
```

Here is the trick to solve your issue, but you actually need to find the script and set it properly, instead just using css trick.